# How do I provide dpkg configuration parameters to aptitude or apt-get?

Tags: debian, puppet, debian-squeeze, chef, gitolite

When installing gitolite I find that:

```
# aptitude install gitolite
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gitolite 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 114 kB of archives. After unpacking 348 kB will be used.
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main gitolite all 1.5.4-2+squeeze1 [114 kB]
Fetched 114 kB in 0s (202 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package gitolite.
(Reading database ... 30593 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gitolite (from .../gitolite_1.5.4-2+squeeze1_all.deb) ...
Setting up gitolite (1.5.4-2+squeeze1) ...
No adminkey given - not initializing gitolite in /var/lib/gitolite.
```

The last line is of interest to me. If I run `dpkg-reconfigure -plow gitolite` I am presented with a dialog and can modify:

- the system user name for gitolite,
- the location of the gitolite repositories and
- provide the admin pubkey.

I'd prefer to use the `git` system user and provide the admin pubkey on installation, say something of the sort:

```
# aptitude install gitolite --user git --admin-pubkey 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDAc7kCAi2WkvqpAL1fK1sIw6xjpatJ+Ms2nrwLJPhdovEY3MPZF7mtH+rv1CHFDn66fLGiWevOFp...'
```

That, of course, doesn't work. Can something similar be done? How do I determine the configuration parameters ahead of time? This would be remarkably useful, for instance, when installing gitolite automatically, via puppet or chef.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I believe that after you run your `dpkg-reconfigure` on an example machine, you can run `debconf-get-selections | egrep "^gitolite\s"` to get what was set. (it's in the `debconf-utils` package if you don't have it).

Then on the CLI, `debconf-set-selections $FILENAME` before running apt.

Then with puppet it would be something like:

```
file {
  "/var/cache/debconf/gitolite.preseed":
     source => '...'; # someplace with that output
}
package {
  "gitolite":
    require      => File["/var/cache/debconf/gitolite.preseed"],
    responsefile => "/var/cache/debconf/gitolite.preseed";
}
```

More info on puppet's site:

- https://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Debian_Preseed_Patterns
- https://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Debian_Patterns
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html

I suspect Chef has a similar mechanism for specifying a responsefile or preseed file or something like that, but I'm not a Chef user.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a [preseed](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) to work around this. See how it is done for Java in [this module](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-java). I find that the easiest way to get a preseed file is to do a manual installation and configuration first, and then getting the seed from that. [This blog](http://blog.hjksolutions.com/articles/2007/07/27/unattended-package-installation-with-debian-and-ubuntu.html) has a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a way to do this with the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package on Ubuntu. Using the above instructions came up with this puppet recipe:

```
        # this is a preseed file which makes it answer the accept EULA when it asks
        # got this content this way: apt install debconf-utils and then run this: debconf-get-selections | grep ttf-mscorefonts-installer
        file {
          "/var/cache/debconf/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.preseed":
             content => "\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/baddldir  error\n\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/dldir     string\n\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/present-mscorefonts-eula  note\n\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula boolean true\n\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/error-mscorefonts-eula    error\n\
ttf-mscorefonts-installer       msttcorefonts/dlurl     string\n"
             
        }
        package { "ttf-mscorefonts-installer":
            ensure => installed,
            require      => File["/var/cache/debconf/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.preseed"],
            responsefile => "/var/cache/debconf/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.preseed"
        }
```