# How do I delete values from the debconf database?

Tags: debian

Per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/332444/why-does-this-preseed-for-gitolite-fail) I've now got wonky preseed values for my gitolite installations such that gitolite fails to install. I need to clear my debconf database of a few keys, but I see no way to accomplish this. Neither did [this fellow](http://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2010/05/msg00119.html), as near as I can tell.

Is it possible to clear the debconf database of a few values?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
echo PURGE | debconf-communicate packagename
```

This will remove ALL the config for this package, so if you want to save some, get them first with debconf-get-selections, then replace the ones you wanted to keep.

You can find all possible actions in the [Debian packaging manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/debconf_specification.html#command_version).
Instead of purging all question of a particular package you can try

```
echo RESET question | debconf-communicate packagename
```

or

```
echo UNREGISTER question | debconf-communicate packagename
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I get debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
0
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied

Comment: @JesseBarnum You need to do it as root!

Comment: That is with sudo