# Cleanup after debconf-set-selections - no interaction installation

Tags: linux, debian, debconf

I have a problem with `debconf-set-selections` command. After I install percona server on my machine root password is located in several cache files. I am not sure if i can just delete this files or entire directory.

```
root@testing:/var/cache/debconf# grep -ir 'superpassword' .
./passwords.dat:Value: superpassword
./passwords.dat:Value: superpassword
./templates.dat-old:Default: superpassword
./templates.dat-old:Default: superpassword
./templates.dat:Default: superpassword
./templates.dat:Default: superpassword
```

So my question would be how to properly clean these files from root password?

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest you only ever use a temporary password in debconf.  Then change it after the system is up with a configuration management tool, or some other method.

Comment: @Zoredache, is there any specific reason for that? Your idea seems to be fine, as well as I am using ansible to manage configs, so not a problem at all, but I thought using `debconf` is more or less fine.

Comment: Well mostly for reasons like you pointed out in your question.  debconf doesn't really work well for storing values that should be kept secure.  BTW, did you see this related question?  http://serverfault.com/questions/332459/how-do-i-delete-values-from-the-debconf-database